# My AM radio receiver using TA7642 IC is not working

Tags: radio, amplitude-modulation

A very simple question I’m sure, but I’m struggling with making an AM radio using an [TA7642](https://www.futurlec.com/Others/TA7642.shtml) AM radio IC.

I’ve looped maybe 200 coils of 0.25 mm enameled copper wire around a 1 cm ferrite rod and made up the attached circuit diagram.

I get static, but Ican’t tune to any stations using the tuning capacitor. Any thoughts on what I’m doing wrong?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please add a data sheet link to the chip.

Comment: Try this: https://manualzz.com/doc/14263320/click-for-data-sheet

Comment: I should not have to wade thru silly web pages to get to that PDF data sheet. Find a direct link.

Comment: You should also wind the coil onto a loose fitting paper former so that you can make significant retunes by moving said former up and down the rod.

Comment: Datasheet says 1.6 V supply maximum, poor headphone impedance match.

Answer (score 1):

A 200 turn antenna coil, on a 10 mm ferrite rod, is far too big for the MW band. A 60 - 80 turn coil with a 365 pF variable capacitor should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a stereo headphone jack & not using the ground. I assume then you must have wired a plug to match with mono headphones to use the two tip & ring connections.

I'd check to be sure that's what you've done otherwise a mono headphones plug will connect to the ground & the tip & since your ground connection is floating you'll get nothing since the power won't be going anywhere & there won't be any sound anyway to go anywhere.

Comment: Hi OM Philip, The view of the stereo headphone plug in the photo confirms the use of stereo headphones. With the socket wired as shown, the headphone elements would be in series and would still work, though not quite well (being out-of-phase). 73, Nandu.